# Show $x^{p}+a$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

first time taking abstract algebra stuck on this question and have no idea how to go about it.
Show that $x^{p}+a$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z_{p}}[x]$: for each $a$ in $\mathbb{Z_{p}}$, where $p$ is a prime number.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Fermat's Little Theorem to show that the polynomial has a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Little tricks are useful to know. Here's one to remember.

So we have $x^p + a \mod p$. Since we are working $\mod p$, and $p$ is a prime, I want you to note that $\binom p k = \frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!}$ is divisible by $p$ for all $ 0 < k < p$. This is because $p$ will be in the numerator in $p!$, but in the denominator, $k!$ and $(n-k)!$ are products of numbers *smaller* than $p$, so cannot cancel out the $p$ from the numerator as $p$ is a prime, so none of these numbers can divide $p$.

Here's the trick:
\begin{split}
x^p + a & \equiv x^p + a^p \mod p \quad \text{ (because  $a^p \equiv a \mod p$)} \\ & \equiv x^p + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom pk x^{k}a^{p-k} + a^p \mod p \quad \text{(by our logic above)} \\
& \equiv  \sum_{k=0}^n \binom pk x^k a^{p-k} \mod p  \quad \text{(Check this yourself!)} \\
& \equiv (x+a)^p \mod p \quad \text{(Ordinary binomial expansion)}
\end{split}

But then, we have factored $x^p + a$ as $(x+a)^p$ $\mod p$.